Using a file parameter inside a docker container in a Jenkins pipeline
I have a pipeline where I run some python script inside of a docker container. I wish to pass a json file to inside the container so that the script can use it. For the sake of argument, let's say that I wish to have the file stored at the folder [pipeline root dir]/json with the name somefile.json (so its full relevant path is [pipeline root dir]/json/somefile.json).
The pipeline uses a git repository to pull the project at each run (i.e. I defined it under GitHub Project in the general settings of the pipeline):

In the gui settings page for the pipeline, I added an option for a File Parameter, which would save a file the user is uploading from their computer at the start of the run into json/somefile.json:

This is how my groovy script looks like (simplified and changed for privacy reasons):
pipeline {
  agent {
    label 'ubuntu:22.04'
  }

  stages {
    stage('main') {
      steps {
        script {
          docker.withRegistry("${SOME_DOCKER_REGISTRY}", "${SOME_TOKEN}") {
            docker.image("${DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME}").inside {
              sh 'ls json'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

However, when I run the pipeline, the command ls json (where I expect my somefile.json to be stored) returns an empty result:

I would appreciate any help on this matter.

Two options:

reuseNode true - make sure the original workspace is mounted, with the parameter file in it.

Stash/unstash - stash the file outside the container and then unstash inside.


